# Javascript get class text inside element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of span4 class elements in my html. they look something like this:

```
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="header">blablabla</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to sort the span4 by that text iside header class.

I do this to sort them

```
$(".span4").sort(sortAlpha)
```

but how do I select the text inside the header class?

I'm doing this but I guess there is a better way

```
    function sortAlphaAsc(a,b){  
        var nomeA = $(a.childNodes[1].childNodes[1]).text();
        var nomeB = $(b.childNodes[1].childNodes[1]).text();
        return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
    };
```

there must be a better way than

```
$(a.childNodes[1].childNodes[1]).text()
```

Comment: $('.span4').find('.header').text()?

Comment: How about `a.find('.header').text()`?

Comment: You don't use that variables in your return statement, simply remove them :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sortAlphaAsc(a,b){  
    var nomeA = $(a).find('div.header').text();
    var nomeB = $(b).find('div.header').text();
    return nomeA.toLowerCase() > nomeB.toLowerCase();  
};
```

Comment: Also, I think you can get away with losing the ternary: `return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase();`

Comment: @undefined, I just copied the OP's code and fixed the part they were asking about. I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

```
var elems = $(".span4");

elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find('.header').text().toUpperCase().localeCompare(
         $(b).find('.header').text().toUpperCase()
    );
});

$(".span4").parent().html(elems);​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9ySW/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You could detach the spans, sort and append them.
That will be very fast too as changing elements in memory and only updating the DOM once in the end is very efficient.

```
var $spans = $(".span4").detach();

var sortedSpans = $spans.sort(function(spanA, spanB) {
    var spanTextA = $("div.header", spanA).text();
    var spanTextB = $("div.header", spanB).text();
    
    return spanTextA > spanTextB;
});

$("body").append(sortedSpans);
```

Obviously instead of `body` you append it back to it's actual container element.

Or if the spans are in a common container store the parent in cache `var $parent = $spans.parent()` and in the end simply do $`parent.html(sortedSpans)`.

I don't know your whole mark-up but that should get you started.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EVFgF/) - Detach spans, sort them and append again

Comment: like the other solutions, you got what i wanted ;) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$('.span4').find('.header').text();
```

This will return the text inside the header div.